# Change value in legend on chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I am using the chartkick gem and can't seem to find any way to change the value in the legend. 
Here is the code:

```
= pie_chart music_services.joins(:membership_type).group(:include_schools).count, library: { pieSliceText: "value" }
```

Now include_schools is a boolean so I get a chart with the legend showing true and false. What I would like the legend to say is if it is true then the text reads "With schools" and if false it would read "Without Schools"

I couldn't find this anywhere in the documentation but I am guessing it must be possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use following format for custom count.

```
<%= pie_chart({"Football" => 10, "Basketball" => 5}) %>
<%= pie_chart [["Football", 10], ["Basketball", 5]] %>
```